# Searching Layout by ID

Tags: android

I am having problem getting a layout's ID.

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_img1" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**.java file**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedStateInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    int imgId[] = new int[] { R.drawable.splash_img1, R.drawable.splash_img2 };
    Random random = new Random();
    int result = random.nextInt(imgId.length);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.splash);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgId[result]));

}
```

Whenever I run this, I get a Gradle build error of "undefined layout".

Comment: You can only find a view by Id if you have set the Id in xml in the first place. using `R.layout.xxx` returns the xml layout file as a whole instead use `R.id.xxx`, which returns an Id of the element/view of interest in a layout file (hence `findViewById`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the `layout` by `R.id.layout_id`.

add id to your `layout` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splash_layout" // <-- this to your code.
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_img1" >

</LinearLayout>
```

add this to your `.java` file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedStateInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedStateInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    int imgId[] = new int[] { R.drawable.splash_img1, R.drawable.splash_img2 };
    Random random = new Random();
    int result = random.nextInt(imgId.length);

    // edit this part.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_layout);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgId[result]));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Doesn't android:id="@+id/splash_layout" conflict with setContentView(R.layout.splash); ie should the latter be setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

Comment: @MikeT View IDs are stored seperately/differently from layout file names/identifiers. So, no it doesn't conflict.

Comment: splending work mate. thanks for the info, been struggling on this for hours

Comment: np mate Haider glad to help :) , and thanks for replying to mikeT @ElvisChweya :)

Comment: Glad to be useful...!